# Adding different texts to html periodically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add text from an array to html. I will take one word at a time from array and add it to the html and i want to stay that word in html for 5 second then clear that word and add the next word from the array to html.

I tried it for one and half hour to get this done. but i can't figure it out how

below is my sample code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <span id="change-text"></span>
    </div>
    <script>
        let texts = ["Alexa", "siri", "Google"]
        let text = document.getElementById("change-text");
        setInterval(() => {
            texts.forEach((element) => {
                text.innerText = element;
            });
        }, 5000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am newbie to javascript, i tried setInterval and forEach to do but i messed up.

Comment: Right now, you are setting all three words directly one after the other, with your forEach loop. You have only delayed the execution of that whole loop by 5 seconds, so it still does all its work in one go. (And then again and again after each 5 seconds.) You need to delay the writing of the individual words - for example by looping over your words, and then calling setTimeout _inside_ the loop. (In that case you will also have to increase your timeout duration though, so 5000 for the first item, 10000 for the second, ...)

Comment: The alternative would be to still use an interval, and then pick the "current" element out of your word item list one by one, for example using a counter variable as index. And then you would need to either clear your interval, or reset the index, when it reaches the number of words, depending on whether you want to go through those words one time, or continously.

Comment: Thank's brother it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use loop inside a `setInterval` function, instead use a counter.

**Whats the issue with the code?**

You are making use of `Array.forEach` inside `setInterval` function. What this does is it loops throuh the array each time when the interval counts, Since you are overwriting the conter of your DOM, it first writes the first element in the array that is `"Alexa"`. Next it updates the same element with `"siri"` and then with `"Google"`. These three updates happen each time when the function inside `setInterval` is executed. You will only see the result of last itration, that is `"Google"`, that why your DOM node is always `"Google"`.

**How to fix this issue?**

You have to update the logic. The logic should be like that the DOM update should happen only once per `setInterval` function execution. I followed the below logic.

- Create a `counter` variable with value 0
- Each time when the `setInterval` function executes, update the value with the value got after division by 3.
- Increment the value each time the function executes.
- This ensures the counter always stay between 0 and 3.
- This help you to access each index one by one when the `setInterval` function executes

```js
let texts = ["Alexa", "siri", "Google"]
let text = document.getElementById("change-text");
let index = 0;
setInterval(() => { 
  index %=  3;
  text.innerText = texts[index];
  index++;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<span id="change-text"></span>
```